# C-create a file

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to create 3 different file that includes random records. There is no problem about creating random records. What's more there is no problem about creating 2 of them. But whatever i do, the file `dataFile2.dat` wasn't created. I am so confused really. Is there anybody who know why?

```
struct record{ char numbers [11],letters[11],date[11]; }; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    writeRecordToFile("dataFile1.dat", 1000000);
    writeRecordToFile("dataFile2.dat", 1000000);
    writeRecordToFile("dataFile3.dat", 1000000);
} 



int writeRecordToFile(char*fileName, int numberRecord)
{
    int i;
    for(i=numberRecord; i>0; i--)
    {
        struct record *newRecord=malloc(sizeof(struct record));
        strcpy(newRecord->numbers,randstring(10,1)); 
        strcpy(newRecord->letters,randstring(10,0));
        strcpy(newRecord->date,randomDate());       

        //createRandom Record // changed of global variable's content
       FILE * file= fopen(fileName, "a");
        if (file != NULL) {
            fprintf(file, "%s,%s,%s\n", newRecord->numbers,newRecord->letters,newRecord->date); 
            fclose(file);
        }   
        else{
            puts("Error handled when appending file");
            return -1;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you see your own error message on that failing file?

Comment: @Jongware no, there is no message on terminal, like there is no problem.

Comment: Did you check that your first file has the expected number of records? You might get in trouble with the memory leak, calling `malloc` 1000000 times.

Comment: Any reason you did not check for the success of `malloc()`? Also, please show us the `struct record` structure. what is the data type of `numbers`? I hope its not `char *`.

Comment: @harper yes i checked it, Also i checked 3. file both of them is ok.

Comment: @SouravGhosh here is the my simple struct 
struct record{
 char numbers [11],letters[11],date[11];
};

Comment: @OğuzhanKAYIŞ Are you sure `randstring()` and `randomDate()` returns a pointer pointing to a memory size `10` or less?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, there is no problem in there. Interesting thing,i try to compile it with small numbers like 10, it works work smoothly. Probably problem is about memory. Do you have any idea for fix that?

Comment: @OğuzhanKAYIŞ hmm. maybe you can add a `free(newRecord)` call after `fprintf()`. Also, i think it will be better if you move `FILE * file= fopen(fileName, "a");` out of the `for` loop. `open` once, inside loop {`allocate ..free`..`allocate..free`} `close` the file.

Comment: this line: struct record *newRecord=malloc(sizeof(struct record)); will malloc some 3,000,000 instances of struct record.  However, the code actually only needs 1 instance.  Also, there is no free() for each of those records.  Suggest having one instance of struct on the stack, perhaps set it to all nul bytes before setting it to the desired values and forget all about malloc and free.  Also, strcpy() will fail to do the desired thing if the receiving field is not already cleared to nul bytes

Comment: open and close are expensive operations, why on earth do them over and over and over and over...?  just open once before the loop and close once after the loop

Comment: rather than 'puts("Error handled when appending file");' it would be much more informative to use perror() (and if your willing to exit the program on an error, follow the perror() with exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

Comment: this format string in the fprintf() function will yield what ever layout the (unseen) functions happen to return. suggest: "%11s,%11s,%11s\n", given the current code, there will be a problem when reading the file as each field will be nul terminated,  might be better to not put the nul terminator bytes into the file.  Especially if the file is to be read as text rather than binary data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is final version (indeed using struct might not be needed here, also I avoided using dynamic memory in the first place).

```
int writeRecordToFile(char*fileName, int numberRecord)
{
    FILE * file= fopen(fileName, "a");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error handled when appending file");
        return -1;
    }

    int i;
    for(i = numberRecord; i > 0; i--)
    {
        struct record newRecord;
        strcpy(newRecord.numbers,"gg");
        strcpy(newRecord.letters,"ww");
        strcpy(newRecord.date,"tt");

        fprintf(file, "%s,%s,%s\n", newRecord.numbers,newRecord.letters,newRecord.date);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: yes i allocated space for newRecord->numbers, the point that i don't understand why 1. and 3. is ok and only 2. has problem. Also i use linux and gcc for compile, i don't know how i can debug it.Do you have any advice?

Comment: A quite obvious optimization is to move the file open and close out of the loop.

Comment: @Jongware:sure didn't think about optimization let OP do it

Comment: i forgot to use free(). Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: this line: struct record newRecord; should be at the beginning of the function, so it is only put on the stack once, rather than the stack added to/removed from for every one of the 3,000,000 passes through the loop

Comment: @user3629249:could be but what's the problem with that? anyway main goal here was help OP resolve the issue I was not much concerned with optimization. Btw like I noted structs are not even needed in this case

Comment: This really is a better answer than mine is.

Comment: @iharob:i think I just removed malloc not much different than that, often dynamic memory is used when there is no need. In any case, structs aren't that much needed in this sample. But op had problem elsewhere initially ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you keep calling `fopen` inside the loop without even calling `fclose`, and `malloc` without calling `free` so you run out of resources, this should work

```
int writeRecordToFile(char*fileName, int numberRecord)
{
    int i;
    /* You only need to open the file once */
    FILE * file= fopen(fileName, "a");
    if (file == NULL) /* check fopen succeeded. */
        return -1;
    /* You only need to call malloc once and reuse memory in the loop */
    struct record *newRecord=malloc(sizeof(struct record));
    if (newRecord == NULL) /* always check malloc return value */
    {
        fclose(file);
        return -1;
    }

    for(i=numberRecord; i>0; i--)
    {
        strcpy(newRecord->numbers,randstring(10,1));
        strcpy(newRecord->letters,randstring(10,0));
        strcpy(newRecord->date,randomDate());

        //createRandom Record // changed of global variable's content
        fprintf(file, "%s,%s,%s\n", newRecord->numbers,newRecord->letters,newRecord->date);
    }
    fclose(file);
    free(newRecord);
}
```

Also, I don't see the point in using a struct for this, and if `randstring` is allocating memory dynamically you still have a memory leak.

Comment: (You missed removing the first `fclose`) (Also, the `fclose` is in OPs loop)